# Magento 1: How to add watermark only for a single category images?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-images, watermark

I have lots of category in my Magento like Electronics, Fashion etc.
But I want to display watermark for Electronics category only. I uploaded water for system configuration but it is applying for all images.

Can anyone tell me how to restrict watermark for one category images only.

Comment: Instead of coding you can set category image catalog->Manage Categories-> select the category and set image there.I hope you know this